# Ionic: Error: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to check some signup fields using the following code:

```
$scope.signup = function()
            {

            if ($scope.signup.spans.name)
                return;
```

This is the html code that refers to `$scope.signup.spans.name`:

```
<span ng-model="signup.spans.name" style="padding: 2px 0 2px 16px; color: red;" ng-if="!check_name()">Please type a valid name</span>
```

However after testing the app, I get stuck at the error:

> Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '$scope.signup.spans.name') signup

So what's wrong with my code? is there any possibility to fix that?

I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need little more code to help, its great if you can share the java script

Comment: You need to create the object signup{ spans: { name: "NameOfSpan" }}};

Comment: if you really want to create a object call "spans" oki. Otherwise no use creating element like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you initialise the controller you have to define `$scope.signup` like this:

```
$scope.signup = {
    spans: {}
}
```

`ngModel` won't automatically create object variables for you

Comment: Ohh .. I missed that. Thanks so much, that solved the problem.